# DELPHI / ACCESS SELECT SQL ERROR

Tags: sql, delphi, ms-access, ms-access-2010, unidac

im using a UNIDAC TUniQuery component, this is my sql:

```
q_ContribSem2.Close;
q_ContribSem2.SQL.Clear;
q_ContribSem2.SQL.Add('SELECT SUMINISTRO.SUMTITIPOPERSONA, SUMINISTRO.SUMCHRAZONSOCIAL, SUMINISTRO.SUMCHAPELLIDOPATERNO,');
q_ContribSem2.SQL.Add('SUMINISTRO.SUMCHAPELLIDOMATERNO, SUMINISTRO.SUMCHNOMBRES, SUMINISTRO.SUMchCodigo, SUMINISTRO.SUMTITIPOCALLE, ');
q_ContribSem2.SQL.Add('SUMINISTRO.SUMCHNOMBRECALLE, SUMINISTRO.SUMCHNUMEROCALLE, SUMINISTRO.OBSERVACIONESMEDIDOR ');
q_ContribSem2.SQL.Add('FROM SUMINISTRO ');
q_ContribSem2.SQL.Add('WHERE ((((SUMINISTRO.OBSERVACIONESMEDIDOR) Like ' + chr(39) + 'NVO*' + chr(39) + ' Or ');
q_ContribSem2.SQL.Add('(SUMINISTRO.OBSERVACIONESMEDIDOR) Like ' + chr(39) + 'NUEVO*' + chr(39) + ') And');
q_ContribSem2.SQL.Add('((SUMINISTRO.OBSERVACIONESMEDIDOR) Like ' + chr(39) + '*JULIO*' + chr(39) + ' Or ');
q_ContribSem2.SQL.Add(' (SUMINISTRO.OBSERVACIONESMEDIDOR) Like ' + chr(39) + '*AGOSTO*' + chr(39) + ' Or ');
q_ContribSem2.SQL.Add(' (SUMINISTRO.OBSERVACIONESMEDIDOR) Like ' + chr(39) + '*SETIEMBRE*' + chr(39) + ' Or ');
q_ContribSem2.SQL.Add(' (SUMINISTRO.OBSERVACIONESMEDIDOR) Like ' + chr(39) + '*OCTUBRE*' + chr(39) + ' Or ');
q_ContribSem2.SQL.Add(' (SUMINISTRO.OBSERVACIONESMEDIDOR) Like ' + chr(39) + '*NOVIEMBRE*' + chr(39) + ' Or ');
q_ContribSem2.SQL.Add(' (SUMINISTRO.OBSERVACIONESMEDIDOR) Like ' + chr(39) + '*DICIEMBRE*' + chr(39) + ') And ');
q_ContribSem2.SQL.Add(' (SUMINISTRO.OBSERVACIONESMEDIDOR) Like ' + chr(39) + '*' + cboAnio.Text + '*' + chr(39) + '));');
q_ContribSem2.Open;
```

---

This statement return rows inside ACCESS but zero rows inside Delphi...

well any idea?

Thanks

Comment: did u tried their support ? they are usually quite responsive. http://forums.devart.com/

Comment: what is table column type of SUMINISTRO.OBSERVACIONESMEDIDOR ? is it string or date ? "Tried Access" what do you mean ? Your database is in Ms Access ? Or u use some unnamed SQL server and u used Access to read data fro mthat server ?

Comment: SUMINISTRO.OBSERVACIONESMEDIDOR Is Text (50) if you want send me your email to atach the project ;)

Comment: Yes, im using MS Access 2010

Comment: The field observacionesMedidor is Text(50), i uploaded the project to 

http://www.unibytes.com/Pe63KcXG8RgLqw-Us4P3UgBB

If you want take a look

Thanks

Comment: did u considered using TAccessApplication ? Also standard SQL requires percent sign not asterisk to expand strings. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx

But i think you'd better to ask their support and also move cboAnio.Text  into query parameter

Comment: ^+1, learn to use parameters from the start, it will save you from headaches later on...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In regular SQL, the asterisk character is *not* a wildcard. The wildcard character that means "match anything" is the *percent sign*, `%`. Unidac offers "server-independent SQL," which probably means that it takes the SQL you give it, which should be in the Unidac-recognized dialect, and *converts* it to the dialect of the database you're targeting, so the SQL you write needs to be valid for Unidac, not necessarily for your actual target database. Unidac will handle the translation. If anything, Unidac is probably taking your asterisks and *escaping* them, so that the target database ends up receiving a request for fields that contain *actual* asterisks in them.

---

A way of determining this by yourself would first be to pare down your SQL until it *does* return something. Then you can gradually re-add pieces of your desired query until it starts to fail again, at which point you've identified which SQL your program has trouble with.

You might also wish to consider storing your dates as *date* fields instead of storing them as Spanish *text*. It would greatly simplify your query.

Also, beware of incorporating `cboAnio.Text` directly into your query. It could offer an *SQL injection* vulnerability. To avoid that, use a parameterized query.